# No puedo guardar un archivo de Excel en la carpeta de descargas

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, asp.net, excel

Tengo un sistema en el cual se ingresa información y se guarda en la base de datos, posteriormente tengo un evento que cuando se de click en el botón obtenga esa información de la BD y la guarde en un arhcivo de Excel en la carpeta de descargas.

Este codigo es el que tengo para obtener la ruta donde quiero guardarlo.

```
        string pathFile = KnownFolders.Downloads.Path + "nombre.xlsx";
```

En la ejecución de Visual Studio si me permite guardar en la carpeta deseada, pero al momento de ponerlo en el IIS local o del servidor me muestra este error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La manera de guardar el archivo es esta:

```
            document.SaveAs(pathFile);
```

Que en este caso **document** es una instancia de la libreria SpreadsheetLight.

No se si me puedan ayudar en que pudiera ser el error o de que manera me recomiendan hacerlo.

PD: Ayudenme si ven que mi pregunta esta mal redactada, porque ya me advierte que tengo varias preguntas no bien recibidas.

Gracias.

Comment: No entiendo en la carpeta descargas de quien queres guardar el archivo.. en la carpeta del servidor?

Comment: no, en la carpeta del cliente que usa la aplicación, de hecho lo probe en el servidor y me da el mismo error

Comment: pero... vos no podes decidir en que carpeta guarda un archivo una aplicacion asp.... la aplicacion vive dentro de iis.. y eso se ejecuta del lado del servidor... deberias darle permisos a iis para que vea esa carpeta.. pero eso del lado del servidor.. vos del lado del cliente, no podes decidir absolutamente nada...

Comment: muchas gracias, aplicare eso de los permisos del IIS hacia la carpeta

Answer (score 1):

Si necesitas que el cliente tenga el archivo excel, debes hacer un flush para que al cliente se le ejecute la descarga del archivo

```
Response.Buffer = true;Response.Charset = "";
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + FileName;
Response.WriteFile(FilePath); //put filepath here

Response.Flush();

Response.End();

}
```

Pero esto debe hacerse despues de tener el archivo físico en alguna carpeta del servidor (carpeta de archivos temporales).